# How to disable right click or set image can't download (protect image in React Js)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, jsx

Is it possible we can protect an image from things like right click and download, or screenshot our image? Here is the tag for the image

```html
<img
    src={pat.name}
    alt=""
    className="absolute "
    style={{
         top: 77,
         left: 20.5,
         zIndex: 2,
         width: 280,
         boxShadow: `0px 4px 8px 2px rgba(3, 21, 49, 0.06)`,
    }}
    />
```

Comment: You can make it more difficult, as the two (current) answers show, but you can't *prevent* a determined user from downloading your image and you *certainly* can't stop anyone from taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really protect an image from being download because it has to be downloaded by the browser in order to be rendered to the user, on the webpage, at some stage.

You can, however, restrict certain operations on images (e.g. right-clicking, dragging the image) which, for the common user, will restrict downloading the image file.

The `pointer-events` CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events. Thus, in the `style` prop, you can add the `pointerEvents: none;` property to disable the context menu when clicking on the image with the RMB.

Related read: [pointer-events on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is adding small script to your website.
For example my open source script:

https://github.com/SjomaNikitin/ImageBlocker/

It's blocking Image downloading with right click and with special extensions.

Or add this line to your page script:

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SjomaNikitin/image-download-blocker/main/ImageBlocker.js"></script>
```